How to expand SQL JSON column to multiple rows using sqlalchemy?
I want to expand a column of type JSON containing an array of strings (aliases of a record) to multiple rows in sqlalchemy 2.0. I get the next SQL query for SQL Server that does the thing but need to write using sqlalchemy.
SELECT * FROM general_info OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(alias) 
From this table:



id
name
alias




1
robert
["bob", "bobby"]


2
alice
null



I would like to get:



id
name
alias




1
robert
bob


1
robert
bobby


2
alice
null




Have you read through SQLAlchemy's Using SELECT Statements documentation yet? What have you tried?

Of course I have, but this operation doesn't seem to be a common use case operation. Additionally, there is not extended support for JSON type operations beyond indexing.

It's trivial to model OPENJSON as what SQLAlchemy calls a table value function, i.e.:
oj = func.OPENJSON(general_info.alias).table_valued("value")

Unfortunately the difficulty is getting OUTER APPLY support for Microsoft SQL Server.
Searching around will turn up the following Github issue, Add APPLY operator support for mssql #5133, from which the following is based upon:
import re
from sqlalchemy import String, func, join, lateral, select, text, true
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mssql
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.sql import Join

# Based on REF:
# Add APPLY operator support for mssql #5133
# https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5133
@compiles(Join, "mssql")
def _compile_join_lateral(element, compiler, **kw):
    statement = compiler.visit_join(element, **kw)
    statement = re.sub(" JOIN LATERAL ", " OUTER APPLY ", statement)
    statement = re.sub(" ON 1(\s*=\s*1)?", "", statement)
    return statement

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class general_info(Base):
    __tablename__ = "general_info"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    alias: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)

stmt1 = select(general_info.id, general_info.name, text("j1.value as alias")).select_from(
    join(general_info, lateral(func.OPENJSON(general_info.alias).table_valued("value"), name="j1"), true())
    )
stmt2 = stmt1.compile(dialect=mssql.dialect())
print(stmt1)
print(stmt2)

print(stmt1) will output the generic SQL statement with JOIN LATERAL:
SELECT general_info.id, general_info.name, j1.value as alias 
FROM general_info JOIN LATERAL OPENJSON(general_info.alias) AS j1 ON true

print(stmt2) will output the T-SQL statement with OUTER APPLY:
SELECT general_info.id, general_info.name, j1.value as alias 
FROM general_info OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(general_info.alias) AS j1

And executing that against your sample data should yield the results:



id
name
alias




1
robert
bob


1
robert
bobby


2
alice
null




Otherwise, is it there any more general or compatible approach to solve this among other database backends, even a less efficient one? Maybe a correlated subquery on JOIN or something similar?

You can't make it a correlated subquery in the select clause on Microsoft SQL Server because openjson() can return many rows.

There isn't really a generic approach to JSON handling in the common RDBMSes. e.g.: while both Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server have json_query() and json_value() functions they're different enough so as to be not interchangeable. While Oracle treats JSON as a native database type that can be queried directly (so you can do things like select t.jdoc.person.birthdate.date() from person_collection t) Microsoft SQL Server kludges it into varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) data types and queries result sets from it using openjson().
